# pipenv set path of virtual environment in vs code

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, pip, pipenv

I'm using visual studio code on windows 10, using python and django. 
The problem I have is that whenever I create a new virtual environment it takes place on its default folder, I'd like to change it to take place in the address I specify.

How can I specify the folder that virtual environment takes place in?

So far, I've tried different ways to solve this problem, but none of work for me, this could be because of the system and tools I'm using,

I've tried setting the path variables using set command, like:

```
set Path="~/.ven"
```

I also looked for changing the variables of pip and pipenv but I couldn't make it work.
I also searched the similar questions on stackoverflow, I couldn't find a proper answer.
Also in the documentation of pipenv, I couldn't find the solution.

Thanks for reading and your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pipenv automatically honors the WORKON_HOME environment variable, if you have it set — so you can tell pipenv to store your virtual environments wherever you want, e.g.:

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.venvs
```

In addition, you can also have Pipenv stick the virtualenv in project/.venv by setting the

```
PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT =1
```

environment variable.

[Custom Virtual Environment Location](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/)

Comment: Thank you for spending your time helping solving my soolution.
So sorry about the delay I've been dealing with some related problems to this issue and some other problems due to the pandemic.
The instruction you gave should have solved my problem, but I read that by creating a folder named ".venv" I can have the virtual environment alongside the project. I think the instruction you gave would have the same effect, If thats true then I must accept your instruction as the correct answer.
Thank you so much for your help sir,

Comment: are you still there?

Comment: Exactly, this is what the environment variable `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1` does, see the documentation here: https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-virtual-environment-location